# Xcode constraints cause error and app crash

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to add constraints to my app. I've done it before and it has been fairly simple. However, when I attempted to add constraints to my app this time, it doesn't product the results I wanted. This is my app.

[image: my app]

I've tried adding constrains one by one on each item. I've tried selected groups of items and setting constraints on height, width, left, right, top, and bottom. Lastly, I've tried adding missing constraints without doing anything else. They all result in it looking wonky like so:

[image: adding missing constraints]

^ adding missing constraints without adding anything else

[image: own constraints]

^ adding my own constraints

[image: own + missing]

^ adding my own constraints then adding missing constraints

This error in my console crashes the app:

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Optional("")
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

I'm not sure how to make these constraints not crash my app and look proper.

Thanks!

Edit: Could it be messing up like this because I'm using an xcworkspace file (running firebase).

Edit: I temporarily fixed it by moving everything to the upper left, which isn't a real solution but it will work for my case. Is there a way to do it with constraints?

[image: fix?]

Comment: Xcode storyboard is always buggy for me. Sometimes it crashes at autolayout, sometimes when you quit and open again it works. Sometimes when I open an existing project the subviews all changed position and everything is a mess. So now I avoid using storyboard autolayout as much as possible. Instead I just programmatically adjust all the subviews relative to the screen size.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis How do you do that?

Comment: For example, I define a public structure to store the screen width and screen height. I create an UIView like: let secondsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, screenWidth/4, screenHeight/5)), then position the view according to screen by: secondsView.frame.orginin = CGPoint(screenWidth/10, screenHeight/10) etc. When you have mutliple subviews like secondsView, minutesView, hoursView, I calculate what's the width and height for them, then calculate what's the space between them. just like what you are doing in autolayout, only do it programmatically.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis That seems like it takes a long time to do, is there a quicker solution?

Comment: Another advantage for programmatically doing this is: you can create several templates (subclass of UIView) with certain arrangement of all the subviews, then create many UIView conviniently. And don't need to open big .xib file, since large .xib file is pain to open.

Comment: Actually it's not that long. Every constraint you add into the storyboard, is just one calculation in the code. People have different preferences though. Maybe some like doing it visually. You can try some a little bit.  I just prefer writing code because it's 100% precise, and never got weird stuff.

Comment: Are you sure your crash is caused by constraints? from your error log force unwrapping is most likely the cause. As for your constraints issue, it is most likely caused by conflicting constraint. Try to show what constraint in each view so we can have better understanding of it.

Comment: @setonugroho You're right, silly mistake on my part. But why are the constraints still acting odd?

Comment: For example, I have lots of menu views containing different number of buttons in it. All in the horizontally center, but stack from above to buttom. So I firstly create a menu button class with all the shapes/colors/functions for the button, then create a MenuView subclass from UIView, with an initializer tell how many buttons I need in this view. Then calculate what's the space between each button, and arrange all the buttons as subviews in MenuView. After that, I can easily create many MenuView with different buttons in it.

Comment: For this particular problem, I suggest just delete all the constraints to see if everything is okay. I sometimes, delete all the constraints, then add them one by one again, to make sure they behave correctly.